How do I test a single JAX-RS/Jersey Endpoint using Spring Boot?
This is similar to testing a single controller with @WebMvcTest, except that we'll be using a real web environment instead of a mock environment. See: Testing the Web Layer guide.

We'll start with an example that's similar to the one in the Testing the Web Layer guide, except that it uses a JAX-RS/Jersey endpoint instead of a Spring controller.
The question is how we can modify an application-level test so that it's an endpoint-level test.


Here's the code for an application that uses a JAX-RS/Jersey endpoint:
Endpoint:
package org.example;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/")
public final class GreetingEndpoint {

    @GET
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}

Jersey config:
package org.example.app;

import org.example.endpoint.MathEndpoint;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

package org.example;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public final class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(GreetingEndpoint.class);
        // register other endpoints
    }
}


Application:
package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GreetingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreetingApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Here's an application-level test that passes:
package org.example;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public final class GreetingApplicationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void helloWorld() {
        assertThat(restTemplate.getForObject(String.format("http://localhost:%d", port), String.class))
                .isEqualTo("Hello, world!");
    }
}

In a real-world context, JerseyConfig may register multiple endpoints. How do I write a similar endpoint-level test that only registers and tests a single endpoint? Even though I'm testing a single endpoint and not the entire application, I still want to use the same testing stack: JUnit Jupiter, AssertJ, and Spring Boot's test library.
(If we were testing a single Spring controller, the answer would be to use @WebMvcTest—though for this question it's fine to use a real web environment instead of a mock environment.)

Using the @SpringBootApplication annotation is the same as using the @SpringBootConfiguration, @EnableAutoConfiguration, and @ComponentScan annotations. See: Using the @SpringBootApplication Annotation in the Spring docs. Here is how we can customize a test application:

We'll create a test component: JerseyTestConfig. This component will register a single endpoint.
The test application will use the @SpringBootConfiguration and @EnableAutoConfiguration annotations.
Instead of using @ComponentScan, the test application will manually @Import the JerseyTestConfig component.
The classes parameter of @SpringBootTest will be used to point the tests to this test application.

Here is the code:
package org.example;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootTest(classes = GreetingEndpointTest.TestApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public final class GreetingEndpointTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void helloWorld() {
        assertThat(restTemplate.getForObject(String.format("http://localhost:%d", port), String.class))
                .isEqualTo("Hello, world!");
    }

    @Component
    public static final class JerseyTestConfig extends ResourceConfig {

        public JerseyTestConfig() {
            register(GreetingEndpoint.class);
        }
    }

    @SpringBootConfiguration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @Import(JerseyTestConfig.class)
    public static class TestApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
}

